# How to return the address of the last occurrence of the substring in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am trying to get my function to return the address of the last occurrence of a substring inside a string (like the address of the variable, not the index of the string). I have tried to indicate where I assume my error is down below.

Once my function is run, my `main()` function should be able to print out `Location of the word is found`.

Here is a simplified version of my Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *lastOccurence(char *str1, char *str2) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while (str1[i] != '\0') { // Calculates length for str1
        str1Length++;
        i++;
    }
    i = str1Length - 1;

    while (i != 0) {
        for (j = 0; str2[j] != '\0'; j++) { // Finds the index of str1, where str2 is found in
            if (str1[i+j] != str2[j]) {
                break;
            }
        }
  
        if (str2[j] == '\0') { // If str2 is found at the index then function returns the address of str2
            
            // ------------------------------------------------
            return &str1[i]; // THIS IS WHERE I SUSPECT MY ERROR
            // ------------------------------------------------
            
            break;
        }
        else { // If str2 isn't found then function repeats at a different index
            i--;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    char sentence[1024] = "Woody the Woodchuck";
    char *word = lastOccurence(sentence, "Wood");

    if (word - sentence == 10) {
        printf("Location of the word is found");
    }
    else {
        printf("Location not found");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are there the variables str and  strLength declared?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow This is a simplified version of my code, I forgot to remove that. The purpose of it this code is to set the variable i to match the last index of str1. The variable str is supposed to be str1, I have made a mistake, sorry about that.

Comment: What is the "simplified version"? If you think that the function does not work then provide the function definition.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sorry about the misunderstanding, but when I said simplified version, I took out parts of my code that didn't have anything to do with this problem. I just provided the code that was needed to be seen. (I provided the main function to let you know how it will be used).

Comment: This statement if (str1[i+j] != str2[j]) { does not make a sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow This statement checks if the index of str1 matches the index of str2, and checks the index to the right to see if it still matches str2. It will keep on going until an index isn't found (making it break) or if str2 is completely found.

Comment: Unrelated, this will hurl undefined behavior like crazy if `str1` ever references an empty string (note: not a NULL pointer; that's a whole different problem).

Comment: @ThanushanS. The initial value of i is i = str1Length - 1; So what is the character at the position i + j?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Near the bottom of the function, there is a line where `i--`. If the position of [i+j] in str1 isn't equal to the position of [j] in str2. Then i will be subtracted by 1, and it will repeat.

Comment: `&str[i]` is exactly (by definition) `str + i`.  Code can often be simplified by using this.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry everyone, I'm not experienced in coding, let alone experience in C. This is the second time I'm dealing with pointers and it's just too confusing for me.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you!! This seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @ThanushanS. There is no such statement in the for loop.